# Decrease run time for program to generate random data

Tags: python, performance

I am required to generate 10GB of random data.

I wrote the following python script to generate required number of bytes by writing string containing printable ASCII characters of random length to each line of file

It takes 3 command line arguments. 
1) Size
2) Minimum Length of string (optional parameter, defaults to 4)
3) Maximum Length of string  (optional parameter, defaults to 10)

This program is neither using memory or doing a lot of IO. What strategy can I use to increase the amount of bytes written per unit time.

```
import random
import sys

K_SIZE = 1000

class Generator:
    def __init__(self,low=4,high=10):
        self.table = {i:chr(i) for i in range(33,127)}
        self.low = low
        self.high = high


    def create_n_bytes(self,total_bytes):
        bytes_created = 0
        """Hack at the moment, this condition will fail only after more than n bytes are 
        written """
        while bytes_created < total_bytes:
            bytes_to_create = random.randint(self.low,self.high)
            bytes_created = bytes_created+bytes_to_create+1
            word=[""]*bytes_to_create
            for i in range(bytes_to_create):
                word[i] = self.table[random.randint(33,126)]
            text = "".join(word)
            #print(str(hash(text))+"\t"+text)
            print(text)

def get_file_size_from_command_line():
    size = sys.argv[1]
    return size

def get_min_word_len_from_command_line():
    if len(sys.argv) > 2:
        low = sys.argv[2]
        return int(low)

def get_max_word_len_from_command_line():
    if len(sys.argv) > 3:
        high = sys.argv[3]
        return int(high)

def get_file_size_in_bytes(size):
    multiplier = 1
    size_unit = size[-1]

    if size_unit == 'M' or size_unit == 'm':
        multiplier = K_SIZE*K_SIZE
    elif size_unit == 'K' or size_unit == 'k':
        multiplier = K_SIZE
    elif size_unit == 'G' or size_unit == 'g':
        multiplier = K_SIZE*K_SIZE*K_SIZE
    elif size_unit in ('0','1','2','3','4','5','6','7','8','9'):
        multiplier = 1
    else:
        print("invalid size")
        exit()

    total_bytes = 0
    if multiplier == 1:
        total_bytes = int(size)
    else:
        total_bytes = multiplier*int(size[:len(size)-1])

    return total_bytes


def main():
    if len(sys.argv) == 2:
        gen = Generator()
    elif len(sys.argv) == 3:
        gen = Generator(get_min_word_len_from_command_line())
    elif len(sys.argv) == 4:
        gen = Generator(get_min_word_len_from_command_line(),get_max_word_len_from_command_line())
    file_size = get_file_size_in_bytes(get_file_size_from_command_line())
    gen.create_n_bytes(file_size)

if __name__== "__main__":
    main()
```

Comment: Are you on linux / unix / OSX? There is a special file /dev/urandom for this purpose.

Comment: why are you making `word` a list and then joining it all to make it a string? you're doing unnecessary list insertion, also you need some `argparse` in this code

Answer (score 4):

First, if you're generating pure ASCII, and you need it to be as fast as possible, it probably going to be faster to generate `bytes` than `str`. You can always call `decode('ascii')` on them if needed, but more simply, just write them directly to `sys.stdout.buffer` or `sys.stdout.buffer.raw`.

That means you can get rid of that table mapping numbers to `chr` values and just construct a `bytes` or `bytearray` out of your ints. (As long as all of the values are in `range(0, 128)`, you're guaranteed the same results, but with one function call with a C loop inside of it, instead of a function call inside a Python loop.)

Also, instead of constructing a list of N empty strings and then replacing them one by one, you can just call `random.choices(range(33, 127), k=N)` and then pass the result to the `bytes` constructor.

While we're at it, as pointed out by Dillon Davis, `randint` is pretty slow; you can get somewhere between 3-5x faster by doing the same logic manually. Which turns out not to matter much here (we're doing about one `randint` for a few hundred `choices`), but still, might as well fix it.

So, putting that all together:

```
def create_n_bytes(self,total_bytes):
    bytes_created = 0
    """Hack at the moment, this condition will fail only after more than n bytes are 
    written """
    chars = range(33, 127)
    while bytes_created < total_bytes:
        bytes_to_create = int(random.random() * (high-low+1) + low)
        word = bytes(random.choices(chars, k=bytes_to_create))
        bytes_created = bytes_created+bytes_to_create+1
        sys.stdout.buffer.write(word + b'\n')
    # necessary if you're doing any prints between calls
    sys.stdout.flush()
```

---

Also, try running the same code in PyPy instead of CPython. It may be 5% faster, or it may be 20x as fast.

---

If you need to squeeze out a bit more performance, all of the usual micro-optimization tricks might be applicable here, like stashing `randint` and `choices` and `sys.stdout.buffer` (or maybe `sys.stdout.buffer.write`—try it both ways) in local variables.

---

If it's still nowhere near fast enough, you need to change things to generate a whole lot more bytes at a time.

That means passing a much larger `total_bytes` value, but it also probably means dragging in NumPy:

```
buf = np.random.randint(33, 127, size=total_bytes, dtype=np.uint8)
```

Now, how do you break this up into words of `low` to `high` bytes? I can't think of anything really clever, but a dumb loop should still be faster than all of the above code:

```
i = 0
while i < len(buf) - self.high:
    i += random.randint(self.low, self.high)
    buf[i] = 10 # newline
sys.stdout.buffer.write(buf.data[:i])
```

This one ends too soon instead of going too far. But no matter what you do, you're obviously going to have to deal with this—the odds that you're going to exactly hit `total_bytes` no matter how you do things are `1/(high-low)`, right?

(It's a bit hacky to slice the `memoryview` returned by `data` instead of slicing the array and calling `to_bytes()` on it, but given the way we created the array it's guaranteed to do the same thing, and it might save a few microseconds, so it might be worth doing with a comment.)

---

If we don't mind wasting memory, we can build an array of random offsets that's guaranteed to be large enough (but will probably be way too large) and then just use that as an index array:

```
sizes = np.random.randint(self.low, self.high, total_bytes//self.low, dtype=np.int32)
offsets = np.cumsum(sizes)
last = np.searchsorted(offsets, 1000)
offsets = offsets[:last]
buf[offsets] = 10
```

The speedup here should be a lot bigger for arrays of, say, 1MB than for something small like 1000 bytes (and it may also be bad for absolutely huge arrays, because of the extra allocation), but it's certainly worth testing.

---

Performance comparisons are going to depend a lot on your platform (including the terminal you're writing to, if you're not redirecting to `/dev/null` or `NUL`), and the parameters you choose.

Using your default values of `low=4`, `high=10`, and `total_bytes=1000` (I used `1010` for NumPy to be fail), running on my laptop (macOS, IPython inside iTerm, not redirecting stdout, CPython 3.7.0 and PyPy 3.5.2/5.10), here are my results:

- Original code: 2.7ms
- Original code in PyPy: 938µs
- My version with `randint`: 911µs
- My version with `random`: 909µs
- My version in PyPy (without `random.choices`): 799µs
- NumPy loop version: 584µs
- Just writing a pre-existing 1000-byte buffer: 504µs

If you subtract out that last one to get the *real* times for the different algorithms:

- Original code: 2.2ms
- Original code in PyPy: 434µs
- My version with `randint`: 407µs
- My version with `random`: 405µs
- My version in PyPy (without `random.choices`): 295µs
- NumPy loop version: 80µs

I'm on a different laptop for the NumPy `randint`/`cumsum` version, but testing it against the original NumPy version, with stdout redirected to /dev/null:

- NumPy loop version: 122µs
- NumPy `cumsum` version: 41µs

So, that's a 3x speedup over something that was already a 27x speedup, so we're talking somewhere in the ballpark of 80x. But writing to a terminal slows things down enough that the wall-clock speedup is only about 5x. (Probably a lot worse if you're on Windows.) Still, not bad.

Comment: PS. "I can't think of anything really clever" should be treated as a challenge to all the NumPy experts. Because there must be a better way to do that part, right?

Comment: Further tip for the non-numpy solution- replace `random.randint(low,high)` with something like `int(random.random() * (high-low) + low)`. For whatever reason, `randint` is ridiculously slow.

Comment: Actually make that `int(random.random() * (high-low+1) + low)`. Also it benchmarks at 5x faster than `randint()` on my machine.

Comment: @DillonDavis Huh, I thought that was fixed way back around 2.7/3.2, but apparently it's still about 3.5x as fast to use `random` in 3.7 and 4x as fast in 2.7.15 (better than 19x as fast in 2.6, but still…).

Comment: @DillonDavis As it turns out, it doesn't make much difference here (which makes sense—we're only doing one `randint` vs. hundreds of `random.choices`), but I'll update the answer.

Comment: @DillonDavis From a quick test, it looks like the time in `randint` is 30% in `_randbelow`, 15% in the extra function calls (`randint` just calls `randrange`, which calls `_randbelow`), 5% in the arithmetic, and 50% in all the conditionals for features we aren't using like `step != None`. Pity `_randbelow` isn't public. It's not that much slower than multiplying `random` even for small numbers, and gets closer fast as the range increases, and unlike `random` it guarantees a good distribution even for a huge range.